# Can I pre-shrink my dojo, dijit and dojox files?

Tags: build, dojo

As I understand the Dojo build, it takes the numerous dojo, dijit and dojox module files, copies them to your releaseDir, minifies them and then concatenates the necessary ones together into your final output file (which will probably be dojo.js).

It occurs to me that there's no need to copy and compress the dojo, dijit and dojox files *every* time I run a Dojo build, since they stay the same.

Is there a way to 'pre-shrink' these files and tell Dojo to use those. Right now, I'm shrinking a bunch of files that I'll never actually include in my final built file. I don't mind doing this *once*, each time I move to a new version of Dojo, but doing it on every build extends my build time and fills my build log with chaff.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Overview

You can point the build tool at an already built set of dojo, dijit, and dojox folders. The dependency resolution will still work since the files retain their `define`s.

The "trick" to not building twice requires that you have any global variables needed in your own module, but that's why you're using AMD anyways.

#### Steps

1. Minify the dojo, dijit, and dojox folders.
2. Without including the dojo related folders, minimize your own source files (w/o the AMD resolver).
3. Run the AMD resolver w/ compress off.